# PDF Javascript submit PDF as email attachment not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, forms, email, pdf

I have a PDF form that has a SUBMIT button (Javascript  that attaches the completed PDF form to an email as an attachment) that customers then send to my company. Works fine just in acrobat, but when using the PDF online in the **chrome** browser, (as the form is on my website to download) the SUBMIT button loads the email, but does not attach the PDF.

Any ideas? Works fine in IE and when using the PDF from Acrobat.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the form/submit button _inside_ the PDF file?  It may just be that Chrome's PDF reader doesn't support JavaScript inside PDFs.

Comment: Yes-the submit button is on the PDF-I suspect the same, that Chrome's PDF reader doesn't support and/or I need to update the code.

Comment: It works in IE because IE uses the Acrobat/Reader plugin so it is able to run the JavaScript required to submit the form. That won't be true in Edge.

Comment: Is there better/updated code out there?

Comment: Is there a way to force a download rather than have Chrome open the PDF in it's browser?

Comment: @Jon Try using the `download` attribute on an `<a>` tag.  https://superuser.com/a/869010

Comment: did and it worked!